# For loop store outcome in variable

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm learning to webscrape data so I can use it to practice data visualization, and I am following a tutorial but I can't get the same results. The problem is that I have a for loop, but cant seem to store the data in a variable. When I run the for loop and try to store the results in a variable i will only get one result, but when i immediately print the for loop results i get all the data.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
for age in team_riders:
  print(age.find('div', class_='age').text)
```

Results:

```
30
28
28
22
34
28
25
30
30
30
34
32
33
32
24
27
23
26
22
27
30
28
24
26
21
26
36
26
27
22
32
30
```

```
for age in team_riders:
  age = age.find('div', class_='age').text

print(age)
```

prints:

```
30
```

Comment: Create a list and append the elements to the list in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an empty list before your loop and `append()` the single results from the loop to this list:

```
lst = []

for age in team_riders: 
    lst.append(age.find('div', class_='age').text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! It worked great! I had already tried to add a list, but had not thought of the append function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this `oneliner`:

```
lst= [age.find('div', class_='age').text for age in team_riders]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm going to try to apply it in the future

Comment: Be aware that this is just a solution to create a list another way, but not if you wanna do other things in your loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing de data as a variable, in this case you are saving the last one (and for every cycle you overwrite the last before), if you want to store every records you need to use a datastructure: List for example, and using **append()**

to add the record to the list.

So your code will be:

```
ages = []
for age in team_riders: ages.append(age.find('div', class_='age').text)
```